# If $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism with kernel $N$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then prove that $f^{-1}(f(K))=KN$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism with kernel $N$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then prove that $f^{-1}(f(K))=KN$

Ok, so what I know from this: $G$ and $H$ are groups that must preserve operation. It is associative, has an identity and an inverse. If this is so, then I could possibly show that the identity of $G$ maps to the identity of $H$, therefore inverse if preserved? The concept of the kernel has always confounded me, not sure why. Any homomophism defines an equivalence relation. The kernel is that relation. If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is nonempty and closed, has an identity and has an inverse.

So, take $K < G$ Show $f^{-1}(f(K))=KN$ when ${kn/ K\in K, n \in N}$ and $ker f=N< G$

so we can say $f^{-1}(f(K)) \subseteq KN \subseteq f^{-1}(f(K))$

I know that there is a similar equation already on this site, but I still need help. Thanks

Comment: @AdamHughes, typo, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually isn't too bad. We know that, by definition,

$$f^{-1}(f(K))=\{g\in G : f(g) = f(k)\text{ some }k\in K\}.$$

But if $f(g)=f(k)$ then

> $$e_G=f(g)f(k)^{-1}=f(g)f(k^{-1})=f(gk^{-1})$$

This line uses the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism so that $f(a)^{-1}=f(a^{-1})$ and similarly $f(a)f(b)=f(ab)$.

From the definition of the kernel we have $gk^{-1}\in N$ i.e. $g\in kN\subseteq KN$, so $g\in KN$. Since $g$ can be any element of $f^{-1}(f(K))$, we have that $f^{-1}(f(K))\subseteq KN$.

Conversely:  if $kn\in KN$ we want to show that $kn\in f^{-1}(f(K))$ so we get the other inclusion. Let $kn\in KN$ then, we note--again by using the homomorphism property that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ and the fact that $f(n)=e_H$ by the definition of the kernel--that

> $$f^{-1}(f(kn))=f^{-1}(f(k)f(n))=f^{-1}(f(k)e_H)=f^{-1}(f(k))\in f^{-1}(f(K))$$

This shows that $KN\subseteq f^{-1}(f(K))$. Since $KN\subseteq f^{-1}(f(K))\subseteq KN$ we have that they are equal.

Comment: ok, give me a minute to process this. I have found that my issue in understanding these type of problems is that I struggle to remember all the definitions and how they work together. Have you found anything that may help that? Or is it really just practice and continuing to work at it?

Comment: @cele I remember my first abstract algebra course made a lot of the students feel just like that. The trick is to basically keep doing it over and over again. It's not so much getting good at it, as getting used to all the new ideas and how they work. I'll edit in some more details to make it easier on you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: I apologize.I lost internet connection yesterday, so frustrating. Now I can look at the problem

Comment: ok, so your first line basically comes from the fact that it is a group, therefore one to one and onto, so we can state that. Your second line in the box comes because we need to use the inverse, since we have that in the problem, right?

Comment: @cele not exactly, the inverse in the problem is a functional inverse, the inverse on that line is because I multiply both sides of $f(g)=f(k)$ by $f(k)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(K))$, then: $f(x) \in f(K)$, so $\exists$ $k \in K$ such that $f(x) = f(k)$. But:

$f(x) = f(k) \Rightarrow (f(k))^{-1}f(x) = e \Rightarrow f(k^{-1})f(x) = e \Rightarrow f(k^{-1}x) = e \Rightarrow k^{-1}x \in ker(f)$

$\Rightarrow k^{-1}x \in N \Rightarrow$ $\exists$ $n \in N$ such that $k^{-1}x = n$ $\Rightarrow x = kn$, some $n \in N$ and $k \in K $ $\Rightarrow x \in KN$.

The other direction is done just as above, reversing the process.

($e$ denotes the neutral element of $H$).